# Numbers Lookup Finding incorrect values

Tags: numbers

I have many tables with two columns (key-value style) and I want to combine all the values in a single table. I lookup key in a first column and insert a value from the second one. I've encountered an issue when a wrong key is looked up. Here is a simple example:

[image]

The `RBYourselfNotUsedRule` is not present in Table 1 and 271 belongs to `RBVariableReferencedOnceRule`. Does anybody have an idea why `RBVariableReferencedOnceRule` was looked up for `RBYourselfNotUsedRule`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `LOOKUP` function can't find the `search-for` value, the function matches the largest value in `search-where` that is less than or equal to `search-for`.  This is why, when the formula cannot find the match, it returns the closest thing it can find.

**From [Apple's Documentation](http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.1/#/ffa597dc7b):**

> LOOKUP(search-for, search-where, result-values) search-for: The value
>   to find. search-value can contain any value.
>
> search-where: The collection containing the values to be searched.
>   search-where can contain any values.
>
> result-values: An optional collection containing the value to be
>   returned based on the search. result-values can contain any values.
>
> **Notes**
>   VLOOKUP compares a search value to the values in the leftmost
>   column of a specified collection. Unless an exact match is required,
>   the row containing the largest left-column value that is less than or
>   equal to the search value is selected. Then, the value from the
>   specified column in that row is returned by the function. If an exact
>   match is required and none of the leftmost-column values match the
>   search value, the function returns an error.

When opting for the exact match, you could wrap the formula in a `IFERROR()` function to catch the "no match" error and return whatever you specify.  i.e.: `""` empty string or other message. `"No Match"` as a example.

You may need to use the more powerful function `VLOOKUP()`.

Example:

[image: VLOOKUP Example]

A more powerful combination of functions to perform lookups is `INDEX(MATCH())`. [This function gives much more power for looking up references without having to know the exact column number.]  For more information and an example, see [*Using INDEX MATCH for Advanced Lookups | Deskbright*](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/).  Even though this reference is for **Excel**, **Numbers** supports these functions just as well.