# Lookup up cell values in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I want to build a simple word translator which may look like this:

- COLUMN A: I have a list of words, each on a row. (1:Airplane, 2:Car, 3:Cat, 4:Dog etc..)
- COLUMN B: I have a list of the same words in another language, each on a row. (1:Aereoplano, 2: Macchina, 3:Gatto, 4:Cane etc..)
- Then I have two cells. In the first one, I can type any word. The second cell is the formula that I want to create. The formula should:

  - check if "my word"(the word that I type) is in the list of column A
  - if it exists, it should return its adjacent word of the second column
  - If no words match, the formula should not return anything.

I'm struggling with finding the correct functions to accomplish this, any pointers are welcome.

UPDATE
I finally found the solution. Best solution for me is
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B7;'Table 1-1'::B4:D53;3;FALSE);0)`
REALLY thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  According to [ask] in the [help], questions should  include what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Can you edit your question to include the ways you tried to solve this problem?  This prevents us from suggesting solutions you've already tried.

Comment: @fsb If somebody doesn't know about `VLOOKUP` and friends, even the first step might be difficult. I wouldn't expect an answer to give a full solution but at least some indications on what to look for.

Comment: After some researches, I found that the simple LOOKUP formula works perfectly for the purpose. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @patrix I didn't see any indication that the OP made an attempt to find the solution.  I know it's difficult to get the idea of `VLOOKUP` across in this type of Q&A setting  (it's best learned via tutorial).  I was trying to avoid a 'try this...' and then 'try this...' back-and-forth and was encouraging the OP to search for solutions first and then let us know what help is needed.

Comment: Your question starts to get confusing, right now it's difficult to see what your actual question is.. It might be better to remove the updates and post them as one comprehensive answer below.

Comment: Sorry Patrick. The topic and question didn't change. I tried to re-edit the text to make my point more clear. In short:  now I tried VLOOKUP instead of LOOKUP but I get a syntax error.

Comment: If you got a solution, great. But *please* post it as an answer below (and upvote/accept it) so people will have it easier to find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282432/120171) to a related question explains how to use `VLOOKUP` in combination with `IFERROR`.

If `VLOOKUP` cannot find the `exact match`, then it throws an error.  To catch this error, wrapping the formula in the `IFERROR` function allows the author to supply a default (in the OP's case, an empty string `""`) to display in the event of no match.

The following example uses a third table to display the translation.  That table is then **locked** so as to protect the formula from being inadvertently overwritten.  The words `NOT FOUND` are used here to show the error event.

**If match is found:**

[image: VLOOKUP no match]

**No match:**

[image: VLOOKUP Match]

**From the documentation:**

> **VLOOKUP(search-for, columns-range, return-column, close-match)**
>
> search-for: The value to find. search-value can contain any value.
>
> columns-range: A collection of cells. columns-range must contain a
>   reference to a single range of cells, which may contain any values.
>
> return-column: A number value that specifies the relative column
>   number of the cell from which to return the value. The leftmost column
>   in the collection is column 1.
>
> close-match: An optional modal value that determines whether an exact
>   match is required.
>
> close match (TRUE, 1, or omitted): If there’s no exact match, select
>   the row with the largest left-column value that is less than or equal
>   to the search value. If you use close match, you can’t use wildcards
>   in search-for.
>
> exact match (FALSE or 0): If there’s no exact match, returns an error.
>   If you use exact match, you can use wildcards in search-for. You can
>   use the wildcard ? (question mark) to represent one character, an *
>   (asterisk) to represent multiple characters, and a ~ (tilde) to
>   specify that the following character should be matched rather than
>   used as a wildcard.

Comment: Ah bjbk! I woke up this morning and I wanted to publish a complete explanation of the process... and you made this gem!! Thanks. That's exactly what I did and you represented in the clearest way. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! If it solves the problem pleas mark as answered for the benefit of others. Cheers!